# Creating Test Class for @RestResource with helper class

Tags: unit-test

Test Class that I am trying to write -

```
@isTest
public class TC_RetrieveProfileFromCareerBuilder_test {
static testmethod void getMethod(){
        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse resp = new RestResponse();             
        request.requestUri ='/services/apexrest/RetrieveProfileCareerBuilder';
        request.httpMethod = 'GET';   
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response= resp;
        String response=JSON.serialize(resp);
        Test.startTest();
        resp.responseBody = Blob.valueof(response);
        TC_RetrieveProfileFromCareerBuilder.doGet();
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

[image]

Getting 72% Test coverage, need more than 80%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning null in test context, please review how to mock HTTP callouts in test classes to cover remaining lines: [Testing HTTP Callouts by Implementing the HttpCalloutMock Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm)